# How to create a Tinder-like stacked card in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tinder, swipecardview

I want to create swipeable tinder-like cards in flutter which can call some function on left or right swipe but it seems too complicated to do so in Flutter. Right now I have implemented the functionality using list view builder with Dismissible which is working as expected and I can update the list via API call while the user is swiping but UI doesn't look that appealing because the card doesn't rotate while dismissing horizontally. I have read many blog posts before posting here and while some of them give an idea to achieve this but it is not possible to update the list in the background with those techniques like using a stack to create a deck of cards as in this example. https://github.com/geekruchika/FlutterCardSwipe

Here's my current code relevant to swiping.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


import 'loader.dart';
import '../screens/profile_overview.dart';
import '../providers/user.dart';

class SwipeProfiles extends StatefulWidget {
  final double deviceHeight;
  final double deviceWidth;
  SwipeProfiles(this.deviceHeight, this.deviceWidth);
  @override
  _SwipeProfilesState createState() => _SwipeProfilesState();
}

class _SwipeProfilesState extends State<SwipeProfiles> {
  List _profiles = [];
  bool _isLoading = true;
  bool _gettingMoreProducts = false;

  _loadMoreProfiles() async {
    print('Reached end of list');
    if (_gettingMoreProducts) {
      print('Already getting products');
      return;
    }
    print('Firestore function called');
    _gettingMoreProducts = true;
    dynamic newProfiles =
        await Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).getProfiles();
    _profiles.addAll(newProfiles);
    setState(() {});
    print('New Products added');
    _gettingMoreProducts = false;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('Getting new products from init state');
    Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).getProfiles().then((profiles) {
      setState(() {
        _profiles = profiles;
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: widget.deviceHeight * 0.75,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: _isLoading
            ? Loader()
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _profiles.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == _profiles.length - 1) {
                    _loadMoreProfiles();
                  }
                  return Dismissible(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                      setState(() {
                        _profiles.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                    background: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.cancel,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                    secondaryBackground: Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: ProfileOverview(_profiles[index],
                          widget.deviceHeight, widget.deviceWidth),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can directly use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tindercard 
or reference source code 
In output you can see the List length did not change and you can detect swipe left or right

```
swipeCompleteCallback:
                (CardSwipeOrientation orientation, int index) {
              print(orientation.toString());
              if (orientation == CardSwipeOrientation.LEFT) {
                print("Card is LEFT swiping");
                print(welcomeImages.length);
              } else if (orientation == CardSwipeOrientation.RIGHT) {
                print("Card is RIGHT swiping");
                print(welcomeImages.length);
              }
            },
```

working demo

[image]

output

```
I/flutter (32086): CardSwipeOrientation.LEFT
I/flutter (32086): Card is LEFT swiping
I/flutter (32086): 3
I/flutter (32086): CardSwipeOrientation.RIGHT
I/flutter (32086): Card is RIGHT swiping
I/flutter (32086): 3
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tindercard/flutter_tindercard.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ExampleHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleHomePageState createState() => _ExampleHomePageState();
}

class _ExampleHomePageState extends State<ExampleHomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<String> welcomeImages = [
    "assets/welcome0.png",
    "assets/welcome1.png",
    "assets/welcome2.png",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CardController controller; //Use this to trigger swap.

    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
          child: new TinderSwapCard(
            orientation: AmassOrientation.BOTTOM,
            totalNum: welcomeImages.length,
            stackNum: 3,
            swipeEdge: 4.0,
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            cardBuilder: (context, index) {
              print('index ${index}');
              return Card(
                child: Image.asset('${welcomeImages[index]}'),
              );
            },
            cardController: controller = CardController(),
            swipeUpdateCallback: (DragUpdateDetails details, Alignment align) {
              /// Get swiping card's alignment
              if (align.x < 0) {
                //print("Card is LEFT swiping");
              } else if (align.x > 0) {
                //print("Card is RIGHT swiping");
              }
            },
            swipeCompleteCallback:
                (CardSwipeOrientation orientation, int index) {
              print(orientation.toString());
              if (orientation == CardSwipeOrientation.LEFT) {
                print("Card is LEFT swiping");
                print(welcomeImages.length);
              } else if (orientation == CardSwipeOrientation.RIGHT) {
                print("Card is RIGHT swiping");
                print(welcomeImages.length);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using pagination to limit the data coming so whenever a user is at the second last card I pull more profiles from API, would it work in such situations? There is an open issue for the same in the repository regarding infinite loading cards.

Comment: this feature did not exist currently. you can try to put your api call here https://github.com/ShaunRain/flutter_tindercard/blob/bda9658fe51e79fcaced9fe1f39e1f73033ecf70/lib/flutter_tindercard.dart#L154

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this same issue and wanted to use the flutter_tindercard package, but it was hard to customize and didn't fit my needs well. As a result, I created the [swiping_card_deck](https://pub.dev/packages/swiping_card_deck) package, which creates a widget for swiping through a deck of cards, either with gestures or buttons. The interface for it is designed to be simple and easy to understand, with defaults that should work well for most use cases. It's also still being developed, so you can create issues for any functionality you want or even contribute to the package yourself. Here is a simple example pulled straight from the documentation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:swiping_card_deck/swiping_card_deck.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: ExamplePage(),
    )),
    title: 'SwipingCardDeck',
  ));
}

class ExamplePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExamplePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final SwipingCardDeck deck = SwipingCardDeck(
      cardDeck: getCardDeck(),
      onDeckEmpty: () => debugPrint("Card deck empty"),
      onLeftSwipe: (Card card) => debugPrint("Swiped left!"),
      onRightSwipe: (Card card) => debugPrint("Swiped right!"),
      cardWidth: 200,
    );
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        deck,
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
              iconSize: 30,
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: deck.animationActive
                  ? null
                  : () => deck.swipeLeft(MediaQuery.of(context).size),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 40),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.check),
              iconSize: 30,
              color: Colors.green,
              onPressed: deck.animationActive
                  ? null
                  : () => deck.swipeRight(MediaQuery.of(context).size),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Card> getCardDeck() {
    List<Card> cardDeck = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
      cardDeck.add(
        Card(
          color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
              .withOpacity(1.0),
          child: const SizedBox(height: 300, width: 200)),
      );
    }
    return cardDeck;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this flutter package [swipe_cards](https://pub.dev/packages/swipe_cards)

To install the package, add the following dependency to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
    swipe_cards: ^1.0.0
```

[image: Swipe Cards Demo]

References:

1. https://pub.dev/packages/swipe_cards
2. https://github.com/AnupKumarPanwar/swipe_cards